# Setting up a water aspirator pump for vacuum distillation

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have a question about the functioning of a water aspirator in a vacuum distillation setup.

I have read about how the water aspirator is hooked up to the water source and the vacuum is in turn connected to the vacuum adapter, and that there should be a splash guard or tubing on one end of the aspirator as well. I'm trying to figure out what to make of the highly suggested use of a water trap. Supposedly the water trap needs to be connected to the vacuum as well as the system.

What outlet is there left to connect to the aspirator, already being connected to the water source and apparatus, as well as the splash guard underneath? Also, if a water trap should be connected to the system, where should it be connected, is a flask with additional adapters required?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the distillate, use the following setup.

[image]

This way if the water pressure drops then the water is sucked into the trap flask, not the distillate.